PDF Creation from OBJ Data (Workshop)
I'm attempting to export my OBJ data into a PDF format.

How would you have a user pick what object they want from a list, and then have the user create a new obj or export the existing selection as a PDF?

Thanks!

You can generate new NotePad document from Notepad templates from Workshop. This is documented here.
In short:

Create a notepad template
Create an input variable (which will contain one object of your required Object Type) and setup the page/what is in the document.
From Workshop, add a "notepad template" button

select the Notepad template you just created (1)
You can configure the button to "pass" inputs to the Notepad template (2)
You can configure the button to directly "Export generated Notepad as PDF" (3)




When the user will use your Workshop application, at some point they will select one object, this will be passed to the button, which on click will instantiate a new Notepad instance from the Notepad Template, and export it as PDF (you can as well save the instantiated Notepad in Foundry).
